# What is the rate of deterioration of lycopene in an open can of tomatoes?

Tags: tomatoes, nutrient-composition

Once I open canned tomatoes and transfer it to a glass jar, what is the rate of deterioration of their lycopene content?

Comment: yes, there are such sites - we don't take this kind of question because there are thousands of foods out there and the answer is the same for all of them.

Comment: Your edit makes this question different from the suggested duplicate, but unfortunately we do not answer questions about nutrient composition (or how it changes over time).

Comment: Hi musiclvr56, we actually do answer questions about nutrient composition, in the very narrow case if you can tell us an exact nutrient you are interested in (this is a rare exception which Erica may have forgotten before commenting). This means we cannot extend the question to multiple unnamed nutrients, or to a general statement like "after X days, it stops being healthy", since this is absolutely undefinable. I can edit and reopen - I know that it might be so narrowed down as for the answers to be useless for you, but it is all we can take on our site.

Comment: I did a quick literature search, and I can't find a study that measures lycopene degredation after a can or jar is opened.  There's lots about loss or gain during processing, but nobody seems to care about the jar once it's opened.